# delay generated from the for loop

Tags: delay, microcontroller, 8051

`//say delay_ms = 1`

`void Delay(const unsigned int delay_ms)`

```
{
unsigned int x,y;
for(x=0;x<delay_ms;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<120;y++);
}
```

}

I am trying to use the C code above for my 8051 microcontroller. I wish to know what is the delay time generated above. I am using a 12MHz oscillator.

Comment: what is the asm/machine code generated by the compiler, and are you using interrupts?

Comment: you need to specify the 8051 microcontroller as well as there are different instruction to clock execution times.

Comment: if you turn on high compiler optimization, your delay would be zero because compiler can skip this code since it doesn't modify anything other than local vars that are not declared volatile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a truly lousy way to generate a time delay.

If you look at the assembler generated by the compiler then, from the data sheet for the processor variant that you are using, you can look up the clock cycles required for each instruction in the listing.  Add these up and you will get the minimum delay time that this code will produce.

If you have interrupts enabled on your processor then the delay time will be extended by the execution time of any of the interrupt handlers that are triggered during the delay.  These will add an essentially random amount of time to each delay function call depending upon the frequency and processing requirements of each interrupt.

The 8051 is built with hardware timer/counters that are designed to produce a signal after a user programmable delay.  These are not affected by interrupt processing (it is true that the servicing of their trigger events may be delayed by another interrupt source) and so give a far more reliable duration for the delay .